# Listing specific attributes within a mixed table

Tags: sqlplus

Hey guys been trying to solve this problem for my project and it's been driving me insane...I've tried everything. According to the directions

"List the Docents (Custid, Custname) whose expertise does not include Van Gogh nor Chagall."

Here are the two tables

CUSTID     CUSTNAME

---

```
  1301 Disney      
  1806 Garcia      
  1502 LaGardia    
  1207 Perry       
  1280 Beecham     
  1822 Becker      
  1140 Klim        
  1509 Roberts     
  1619 Robins      
  1111 Bardot      
  1515 David       
  1701 Martin      
  1904 Gross       
  1236 Brooks      
  1430 Todd
```

CUSTID SPECIALTY

---

```
  1430 Dufy
  1430 Monet
  1430 Van Gogh
  1502 Chagall
  1502 Cubism
  1502 Van Gogh
  1619 Da Vinci
  1822 Italian Renaissance
  1904 Chagall
  1904 Van Gogh
```

I've tried doing

```
SQL> select customer.custid,customer.custname
   from customer,docent_expertise        
   where customer.custid=docent_expertise.custid     
   and specialty not in ('Van Gogh','Chagall')
   group by customer.custid,customer.custname;
```

and my results yield

```
CUSTID      CUSTNAME
---------- -----------
1822        Becker
1619        Robins
1430        Todd
1502        LaGardia
```

If you can see Cust 1430 and 1430 should not be in there!!
Please help!!

Please feel free to ask for more clarity for I know my question may seem a bit vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customer 1502 shouldn't be in the result either since he/she has "Van Gogh" speciality.
This should work:

```
select customer.custid,customer.custname
from   customer,docent_expertise
where  customer.custid=docent_expertise.custid     
and    customer.custid not in (select custid
                               from   docent_expertise
                               where  specialty in ('Van Gogh','Chagall')
                              );
```

Output:

```
CUSTID  CUSTNAME
------  --------
1619    Robins
1822    Becker
```

Comment: And yes I did mean to not include chagall in which i forgot to write that down!